# How to test Job states for a Apex Test with CronTrigger being read only?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup, apexmock

I have the following function in a class that implements System.Schedulable:

```
@TestVisible private void rescheduleJob(CronTrigger me, ISchedulable item, MySchedulableContext myCtx) {
        if (me.State != 'COMPLETE' && me.State != 'ERROR' && me.State != 'DELETED'){
                try {
                System.abortJob(me.Id);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug('Could not abort the job');
                }
            }
        String newTrigger = item.getNextTriggerString(myCtx);
        if (newTrigger != null && newTrigger.length() > 0) {
            try {
                System.schedule(me.CronJobDetail.Name+ '-' + System.currentTimeMillis(), newTrigger, this);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('Unable to start the job');
            }

        }
    }
```

I would like to write two tests:
1). Where an invalid job or aborted job is passed in
2). A valid job is passed in

The issue is that I am unable to change CronTrigger with it being read only. I have ApexMocks installed but dont know if that can be mocked or is even the right approach. I just want to make sure the system.schedule and system.abortjob perform as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, I'd optimize away the bits that really don't matter:

```
@TestVisible private void rescheduleJob(CronTrigger me, ISchedulable item, MySchedulableContext myCtx) {
    try {
        System.abortJob(me.Id);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Could not abort the job');
    }
    String newTrigger = item.getNextTriggerString(myCtx);
    if (newTrigger?.length() > 0) {
        try {
            System.schedule(me.CronJobDetail.Name+ '-' + System.currentTimeMillis(), newTrigger, this);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Unable to start the job');
        }
    }
}
```

If you're going to just swallow the exception anyways (which in this case, is probably justified), I'd skip checking the state before aborting. What's the worst that'll happen? It'll throw an exception that you're already catching?

Of course, do make sure to document that you're doing this intentionally:

```
// Try to abort. Success is optional, so we just ignore failures.
```

I also would recommend not just debugging away *starting* a job, that is probably an error someone needs to see. It should be logged somewhere.

Also, even though the object *is* read-only, you can still use the JSON trick to make a fake record:

```
CronTrigger fakeTrigger = (CronTrigger)JSON.deserialize('{"State":"Running"}', CronTrigger.class);
```

You do need to pass in "reasonable" values (e.g. don't put a number in a String field), but you can generally create all kinds of fake records using this technique. Providing a fake Id for the Id field will, of course, fail (the exception would be thrown), but since you're ignoring those exceptions, it simply doesn't matter.

Finally, mocking might be an option; if you had a wrapper for the CronTrigger as you did the other two, you could use dependency injection to create fake state values, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock a CronTrigger, you can use the JSON serialize/deserialize approach (see sfdcfox answer which is concise and works nicely for simple mocking)

My favorite library for read-only fields is [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) by @mattaddy

```
CronTrigger[] mockCronTriggers = new List<CronTrigger> {
            (CronTrigger) new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronTrigger.class)
                .setParent('CronJobDetail',new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronJobDetail.class)
                            .setField(CronJobDetail.Name,'00JobComplete'))
                .setField(CronTrigger.Id,fflib_IDGenerator.generate(CronTrigger.SObjectType))
                .setField(CronTrigger.State,Util.CronTriggerState.COMPLETE.name())
                .setField(CronTrigger.NextFireTime,Util.now.addMinutes(5))
                .toSObject(),
            (CronTrigger) new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronTrigger.class)
                .setParent('CronJobDetail',new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronJobDetail.class)
                            .setField(CronJobDetail.Name,'01JobInFlight'))
                .setField(CronTrigger.Id,fflib_IDGenerator.generate(CronTrigger.SObjectType))
                .setField(CronTrigger.State,Util.CronTriggerState.EXECUTING.name())
                .toSObject(),
            (CronTrigger) new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronTrigger.class)
                .setParent('CronJobDetail',new sfab_FabricatedSObject(CronJobDetail.class)
                            .setField(CronJobDetail.Name,'02JobPending'))
                .setField(CronTrigger.Id,fflib_IDGenerator.generate(CronTrigger.SObjectType))
                .setField(CronTrigger.State,Util.CronTriggerState.WAITING.name())
                .setField(CronTrigger.NextFireTime,Util.now.addMinutes(5))
                .toSObject()
    };
```

I find `SObjectFabricator` easier to use for mocking Sobjects than `fflib_ApexMocksUtils` when it comes to expressing relationships but regardless, the ApexMocks library would have you do this:

```
CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger();
ct = (CronTrigger)fflib_ApexMocksUtils.setReadOnlyFields(
            ct,
            CronTrigger.class,
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{CronTrigger.State => 'COMPLETED,
                                          ...}
    );
```

and then you can use `ct` in the argument to your method under test

You can see how to use `fflib_ApexMocksUtils` by looking at the testmethod for that class